# How to handle special characters in LDAP query

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I use ldapsearch on Ubuntu to

- access an LDAP server
- create a cache-file from the returned results to lookup addresses, phone-numbers, etc.

To create the cache file I use this command

```
ldapsearch -h ldap.example.domain -LLL -D cn=***,cn=***,dc=***,dc=*** -W -s one -b cn=***,dc=***,dc=*** "cn=*" sn givenName
```

works out, for most of the cases, but if I search the cache-file for names, containing [umlaut characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29) (e.g. `üöäß`), no results are returned.

Reason:

```
Max Müller
```

for example is encoded as

```
Max TcO8bGxlcg==
```

by the LDAP server and therefore unusable within the  cache file. Is there any possibility to resolve this?

Note: I cannot change the results of the LDAP server itself, since I have no root access to it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is normal for LDAPSEARCH results. Generally, you should not need to create a cache file as LDAP is very fast. The values you see in the result are base64 encoded.

You could use something like the [UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/index.html) which has a memory based LDAP server  that could run locally.